# Qt C++ Set Set Vtk Axis Scake

Tags: c++, qt, vtk

I have the following code where i plot points in 3d space:

```
     vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints> points =
            vtkSmartPointer<vtkPoints>::New();

        for(int in = 0; in<x.size(); in++)
        {
            points->InsertNextPoint (x[in], y[in], ry[in]);
        }

          vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> pointsPolydata =
            vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData>::New();

          pointsPolydata->SetPoints(points);

          vtkSmartPointer<vtkVertexGlyphFilter> vertexFilter =
            vtkSmartPointer<vtkVertexGlyphFilter>::New();
        #if VTK_MAJOR_VERSION <= 5
          vertexFilter->SetInputConnection(pointsPolydata->GetProducerPort());
        #else
          vertexFilter->SetInputData(pointsPolydata);
        #endif
          vertexFilter->Update();

          vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData> polydata =
            vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyData>::New();
          polydata->ShallowCopy(vertexFilter->GetOutput());

          // Setup colors
          unsigned char red[3] = {255, 0, 0};
          unsigned char green[3] = {0, 255, 0};
          unsigned char blue[3] = {0, 0, 255};

          vtkSmartPointer<vtkUnsignedCharArray> colors =
            vtkSmartPointer<vtkUnsignedCharArray>::New();
          colors->SetNumberOfComponents(3);
          colors->SetName ("Colors");
          colors->InsertNextTupleValue(red);
          colors->InsertNextTupleValue(green);
          colors->InsertNextTupleValue(blue);

          polydata->GetPointData()->SetScalars(colors);

          // Visualization
          vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper> mapper =
            vtkSmartPointer<vtkPolyDataMapper>::New();
        #if VTK_MAJOR_VERSION <= 5
          mapper->SetInputConnection(polydata->GetProducerPort());
        #else
          mapper->SetInputData(polydata);
        #endif

          vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor> actor =
            vtkSmartPointer<vtkActor>::New();
          actor->SetMapper(mapper);
          actor->GetProperty()->SetPointSize(5);

          vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer> renderer =
            vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderer>::New();
          vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow> renderWindow =
            vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindow>::New();
          renderWindow->AddRenderer(renderer);
          vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor> renderWindowInteractor =
            vtkSmartPointer<vtkRenderWindowInteractor>::New();
          renderWindowInteractor->SetRenderWindow(renderWindow);

          renderer->AddActor(actor);

          this->ui->qvtkWidget->GetRenderWindow()->AddRenderer(renderer);
          renderWindowInteractor->Start();
```

When I get the resulting plot. All the points are plotted, but is hard to see anything due to the default scale. What I'm not sure is how to zoom in the view on the z axis. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This shouldn't have anything to do with being inside Qt right? You should remove the Qt dependence from the example, and add the includes so it is compilable for us. Have you tried holding the right mouse button and dragging? This how you zoom with the vtkInteractorStyleTrackballActor which I believe is the default InteractorStyle for vtkRenderWindowInteractor.